# Comma separated shortcode wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to separate several shortcodes by comma. Currently line is

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[bangla_date]' . ',' . '[bangla_time]' . '.' . '[bangla_day]'); ?>
```

The output displayed on the website is a single line with no space in betwwen the shortcodes. Please help.

Comment: Am I missing something? There aren't any spaces in your example to be output.

Comment: Ok ...right ..I want just a comma seperator ...Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try simply adding spaces:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[bangla_date]' . ',&nbsp;' . '[bangla_time]' . ',&nbsp;' . '[bangla_day]'); ?>
```

(`',' => ',&nbsp;'`)